# Pandas Aggregate data other than a specific value in specific column

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have my data like this in pandas dataframe python

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
         'ID':range(1, 8),
         'Type':list('XXYYZZZ'),
         'Value':[2,3,2,9,6,1,4]

})
```

The oputput that i want to generate is

[image]

How can i generate these results using python pandas dataframe. I want to include all the **Y** values of type column, and does not want to aggregate them.

Comment: What is filter?

Comment: Type column is the filter

Comment: because of order.

Comment: Super, I understand now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First filter values by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing), aggregate and append filter out rows, last sorting:

```
mask = df['Type'] == 'Y'
df1 = (df[~mask].groupby('Type', as_index=False)
                .agg({'ID':'first', 'Value':'sum'})
                .append(df[mask])
                .sort_values('ID'))
print (df1)
   ID Type  Value
0   1    X      5
2   3    Y      2
3   4    Y      9
1   5    Z     11
```

If want range `1` to `length of data` for `ID` column:

```
mask = df['Type'] == 'Y'
df1 = (df[~mask].groupby('Type', as_index=False)
                .agg({'ID':'first', 'Value':'sum'})
                .append(df[mask])
                .sort_values('ID')
                .assign(ID = lambda x:  np.arange(1, len(x) + 1)))
print (df1)
   ID Type  Value
0   1    X      5
2   2    Y      2
3   3    Y      9
1   4    Z     11
```

Another idea is create helper column for unique values only for `Y` rows and aggregate by both columns:

```
mask = df['Type'] == 'Y'
df['g'] = np.where(mask, mask.cumsum() + 1, 0)

df1 = (df.groupby(['Type','g'], as_index=False)
        .agg({'ID':'first', 'Value':'sum'})
        .drop('g', axis=1)[['ID','Type','Value']])

print (df1)
   ID Type  Value
0   1    X      5
1   3    Y      2
2   4    Y      9
3   5    Z     11
```

Similar alternative with Series `g`, then `drop` is not necessary:

```
mask = df['Type'] == 'Y'
g = np.where(mask, mask.cumsum() + 1, 0)
df1 = (df.groupby(['Type',g], as_index=False)
        .agg({'ID':'first', 'Value':'sum'})[['ID','Type','Value']])
```

Comment: What if i had to provide multiple options ? e.g Y and X ?

Comment: @AhsanMukhtar - So do you need first or last solution use? What need change for `X,Y` match ?

Comment: It's okay, i figured it out. 

i needed to add .isin() operator instead of ==. 
Thanks

Comment: can you explain what this line does? 
g = np.where(mask, mask.cumsum() + 1, 0)

Comment: Yes, need same. `g = np.where(mask, mask.cumsum() + 1, 0)` means create new array with cumulative sum of Trues of mask with 1 only for True values, else 0 - in other words it create counter only for matched rows, else 0